# fastest way I can insert large query

Tags: sql, jdbc, insert, large-data

I have a query to insert like

```
insert into test (city,State,City,number,Sales,Quantity)
select 'AAA','Texas ','SSS',115121,79,1 
UNION ALL 
select 'BBB','Texas ','WWW',144921,338,2 UNION ALL
```

and 45000 record more.
What is the fastest way I can insert this query. I want to insert it with batch or bulk upload. Please help.

Comment: Which database are you working with? 45k rows isn't that much, especially if it's a one-time operation. So _how_ fast does it have to be?

Comment: I am working on SQL SERVER